# Strange result with tangent space normal map

Tags: opengl, glsl

Here is my problem, I tried to add a procedure to handle the tangent space normal map into my original shaders, which use the BlinnPhone Lighting model, the BlinnPhone Light model works fine

[image: BlinnPhone Light]

But, when I tried to transform the tangent space normal(sampled from the normal map), **if I combined the matrix, which can transform the normal from tangent space to world space in one time(because the TBN already multiplied the world transform matrix), then I always got the wrong lit result**:

[image: Wrong result]

But, if I combined the TBN matrix, which only convert tangent space to object (model) space in the vertex shader, and pass the world transform matrix to fragment shader, **then I convert the normal twice, once with the TBN to convert the normal to object(model) space, then convert it to the world space, finally I can got the right result**.

[image: right result]

**I suspect there is something wrong with the normalize function with my first method (transform normal in one time)**, But I couldn't find where is my problem.
Help me, Thank you.

**PS: The attached code segment is default use the the method 2, but you can simply convert the whole method to method 2, by uncomment the line in vertex shader with comment "for method 1", then comment the line in fragment shader with comment "not for method 1".**

**vertex shader:**

```
#version 450 core
#pragma debug(on)

layout (location = 0) in vec3 vPosition;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 in_uv;
layout (location = 2) in vec3 vTangent;
layout (location = 3) in vec3 vBitangent;
layout (location = 4) in vec3 vNormal;

uniform mat4x4 mat_mvp;
uniform mat4x4 mat_world;

//----out vars
out vec2 uv;
out vec3 worldNormal;
out vec3 worldPos;
out mat3x3 tangentToModelMat;
out mat4x4 worldMat;
precise out vec3 testV;
out float f1;
out float f2;
out float f3;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = mat_mvp * vec4(vPosition, 1);

    worldPos = (mat_world * vec4(vPosition, 1)).xyz;

    vec3 T = normalize(mat3(mat_world) * vTangent);
    //T = mat3(mat_world) * vTangent;
    vec3 B = normalize(mat3(mat_world) * vBitangent);
    //B = mat3(mat_world) * vBitangent;
    vec3 N = normalize(vNormal * inverse(mat3(mat_world)));
    //N = vNormal * inverse(mat3(mat_world));

    // re-orthogonalize T with respect to N
    //T = (T - dot(T, N) * N);

    B = cross(N, T);

    tangentToModelMat[0] = vTangent;
    tangentToModelMat[1] = vBitangent;
    tangentToModelMat[2] = vNormal;
    //tangentToModelMat = mat3(T, B, N);//for method 1

    worldNormal = normalize(vNormal * inverse(mat3(mat_world)));

    uv = in_uv;
    worldMat = mat_world;
}
```

**fragment shader:**

```
#version 450 core

layout (location = 0) out vec4 fColor;

uniform vec3 worldCamPos;

uniform sampler2D tex;
uniform sampler2D normalMap;

//----in vars
in vec2 uv;
in vec3 worldNormal;
in vec3 worldPos;
in mat3x3 tangentToModelMat;
in mat4x4 worldMat;
precise in vec3 testV;
in float f1;
in float f2;
in float f3;

void main()
{
    // assumption directional light color and dir
    vec3 worldLightColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
    vec3 worldLightDir = vec3(1, -1, -1);
    worldLightDir = normalize(worldLightDir);

    // assumption ambient light color
    vec3 ambient = vec3(1, 1, 1);
    // assumption diffuse color
    vec3 diffuseColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);
    // assumption specular color
    vec3 specularColor = vec3(1, 1, 1);

    // Get "normal" from the normalmap
    vec3 normal = texture(normalMap, uv).rgb;
    normal = normal * 2 - 1;
    normal = normalize(tangentToModelMat * normal);
    normal = normalize(mat3(worldMat) * normal);//not for method 1

    vec3 viewDir = normalize(worldCamPos - worldPos);
    vec3 halfDir = normalize(viewDir + worldLightDir);

    vec4 albedo = texture(tex, uv);
    ambient = ambient * 0.7 * albedo.rgb;
    vec3 diffuse = worldLightColor * ambient.rgb * clamp(dot(worldLightDir, normal), 0.0, 1.0);

    float spec = pow(max(dot(halfDir, normal), 0.0), 512);
    vec3 specular = worldLightColor * specularColor.rgb * spec;

    fColor = vec4(ambient + diffuse + specular, 1);
    //fColor = vec4(albedo.rgb, 1);
    //fColor = albedo;
    //fColor = vec4(f1, f2, f3, 1);
}
```

Comment: Please note, the name is [Blinn–Phong](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinn%E2%80%93Phong_reflection_model) rather than "BlinnPhone"

Comment: Method 1 clearly throws away the information from `vBitangent`. The whole "re-orthogonalize" shenanigans found in so many tutorials are _wrong_ anyway - they are a cheap - and in many cases bad - approximation to use `transpose(mat3(T,B,N))` instead of `inverse(mat3(T,B,N))` when going from world space to tangent space and to do lighting there (which could be theoretically a bit faster because you don't have to re-transform the normal from the normal map at each fragment, but can use it as-is.

Comment: However, since you use lighting in world space, you don't need any inverse of that matrix, and so you don't need to apply weird tricks to approximate the inverse either, it is only going to break your tangent space.

Comment: Does it change anything if you do `tangentToModelMat = mat3(mat_world) * mat3(vTangent, vBitangent, vNormal)`?

Comment: @Rabbid76, thank you for the naming correction, and when I did the change you mentioned, I got the right lighting result, but the funny thing is, the whole method 1 works fine in Unity ShaderLab:  
     `fixed3 worldNormal = UnityObjectToWorldNormal(v.normal);
     fixed3 worldTangent = UnityObjectToWorldDir(v.tangent.xyz);
     fixed3 worldBinormal = cross(worldNormal, worldTangent) * v.tangent.w;
`  , any idea of that?

Comment: @derhass, thank you for the information, I will keep in mind.

Comment: @Rabbid76, `inline float3 UnityObjectToWorldDir( in float3 dir )
{
    return normalize(mul((float3x3)unity_ObjectToWorld, dir));
}
inline float3 UnityObjectToWorldNormal( in float3 norm )
{
#ifdef UNITY_ASSUME_UNIFORM_SCALING
    return UnityObjectToWorldDir(norm);
#else
    // mul(IT_M, norm) => mul(norm, I_M) => {dot(norm, I_M.col0), dot(norm, I_M.col1), dot(norm, I_M.col2)}
    return normalize(mul(norm, (float3x3)unity_WorldToObject));
#endif
}`